# Scrollbar is moving entire div

Tags: html, css

I'm writing an HTML program that will create a chat window.

And I have 3 divs and in the bottom div I'll enter text and my HTML is as below.

```
<div class="chatbox" id="chatbox" style="margin: 0px;">
                <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.41.0.min.js"></script>
                <div class="chatHeader">
                    <span class="chat-text" style="text-align: center;">Chat with Care!!</span>
                    <div id="close-chat" onclick="closeChatbox()">×</div>
                    <div id="minim-chat" onclick="minimChatbox()" style="display: block;">
                        <span class="minim-button">−</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="maxi-chat" onclick="loadChatbox()" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="maxi-button">+</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chatBody" style="margin-top:13%">
                    <ul id="ulid">
                        <li class="lexResponse">Hi I am CARE..Your Personal Assistant</li>
                    <li class="me">Hi THere</li><li class="lexResponse"><div>Sorry, can you please repeat that?</div></li><li class="me">H there</li><li class="lexResponse"><div>Sorry, can you please repeat that?</div></li><li class="me">start the fl;ow</li><li class="lexResponse"><div>what is your budget? is it very high, high, low or medium?</div></li><li class="me">Start the flow</li><li class="lexResponse"><div>what is your budget? is it very high, high, low or medium?</div></li></ul>
                </div>
                <form class="chat-form" onsubmit="return pushChat()">
                    <div class="backgroundColor">
                        <input type="text" id="textinput">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Here when I added my CSS, I need a scrollbar for the center div(I'm getting this), but when I scroll the bar, the bottom div is also moved.

please let me know on how can I fix the bottom div to bottom and have scroll bar only to the center div.

Here is a working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/g87mfLxa/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles to the chatBody class.

```
    `.chatBody {
      overflow: auto;
      height: 70%;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
     }`
```

remove 
        `overflow: auto` 
from chatBox.

Hope this is what you meant.

The updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g87mfLxa/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost close. You just need to change the position to `position:sticky` in your CSS in class `chat-form`. To give it better look you may wish to remove horizontal scroll bar. Your CSS got two changes in the CSS classes below . See this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bra3bcb/).

```
.chatbox {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 85%;
    bottom: 0.5%;
    right: 1%;
    margin: 0 0 -1500px;
    background: white;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.chat-form {
  position: sticky;
  /* bottom: 0px; */
  bottom: 0;
  /* margin-top: 4%; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Let me know If It was helpful.